# waaaaaaay too many svchosts running and causing 1st logical cpu load to increase

Tags: windows, intel-core-i5, svchost

[image: taskmanager screenshot of svchost processes]
[image]

[Original Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xeGK.jpg)

i've searched the net, and apparently this should be normal. in forums, i see people having 8, 10, even 20 instances. but i counted mine, and it reached 68. maybe this is the reason why one core of my cpu is way more loaded than the others, affecting my gaming experience. please help :(

here's a screenshot of process explorer and the cpu load graphs: 
[Process Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB6a7.png)

Comment: I would install Process Hacker, which is a task manager replacement. It'll show you exactly what is behind every process in a detailed manner.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Windows 10 version 1703, 64bit systems with more than 3.5GB RAM run each service in its own service host.
The resource saving rationale of running several services in the same host has been outweighed by the reliabity aspects.

Microsoft announcement explaining change:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/10/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14942-for-pc/#1pJTJqBmb0DjY27P.97

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process Explorer by System Internals to see what services these svchosts are running. If the exes aren't in the right place you might have a virus problem.